# How to properly subclass a delegate property in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, inheritance

In subclassing a class, I want to also subclass a delegate of the parent class given that the subclass now has additional functionality.  What's the best way to go about doing this? If I just declare another delegate property in the subclass with the same name I would get a warning "Property type 'id' is incompatible with type 'id' inherited from 'ParentClass'

Answer (score 20):

Given this example that produces the warning:

```
// Class A
@protocol ClassADelegete;

@interface ClassA : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<ClassADelegete> delegate;
@end

@protocol ClassADelegete <NSObject>
- (void)classADidSomethingInteresting:(ClassA *)classA;
@end

// Class B
@protocol ClassBDelegete;

@interface ClassB : ClassA
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<ClassBDelegete> delegate; // Warning here
@end

@protocol ClassBDelegete <ClassADelegete>
- (void)classBDidSomethingElse:(ClassB *)classB;
@end
```

Two solutions that remove the warning are.

1) In the subclass, place the protocol definition before the class definition. This is what `UITableViewDelegate` in `UITableView.h` does:

```
// Class B
@class ClassB;

@protocol ClassBDelegete <ClassADelegete>
- (void)classBDidSomethingElse:(ClassB *)classB;
@end

@interface ClassB : ClassA
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<ClassBDelegete> delegate;
@end
```

2) In the subclass, add the original protocol alongside the new one:

```
// Class B
@protocol ClassBDelegete;

@interface ClassB : ClassA
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<ClassADelegete, ClassBDelegete> delegate;
@end

@protocol ClassBDelegete <ClassADelegete>
- (void)classBDidSomethingElse:(ClassB *)classB;
@end
```

I assume (1) works as Apple do it this way, Option (2) removes the warning but I haven't compiled and run anything setup this way.

Comment: Maybe a bit late for this but what about the same example, but only ClassADelegete and ClassBDelegete are in Swift and ClassA and ClassB remain in Objective C? I can't get rid of the warning in this case.

Comment: option (1) works, but we also need to add  `@dynamic delegate;` in ClassB,

Answer (score 2):

Follow the example of `NSTableView` and `NSOutlineView`.

`NSOutlineView` is a subclass of NSTableView, and defines its own protocol for its `dataSource` and `delegate`.

`NSTableView` declares its delegate this way:

```
- (void)setDelegate:(id <NSTableViewDelegate>)delegate;
- (id <NSTableViewDelegate>)delegate;
```

and `NSOutlineView`:

```
- (void)setDelegate:(id <NSOutlineViewDelegate>)anObject;
- (id <NSOutlineViewDelegate>)delegate;
```

Apparently the compiler is more lenient with bare method declarations than it is with property declarations.

Unlike NSTable/OutlineView, you might want to make the subclass's protocol inherit from the base class's protocol, e.g.

```
 @protocol SpecializedProtocol <BaseProtocol>
```

... it probably depends on the situation.

Comment: I went with the latter route (subclass the delegate protocol after subclassing the main class), but was unable to declare another delegate property without triggering the compiler error.  Is the method declarations you mentioned the only way to make the compiler happy?

Comment: I don't know of any other way to do it.