# Property type '' is incompatible with type '' inherited from ''

Tags: objective-c, compiler-warnings

I created a `BaseRequest` Class and it has a property `params`, which is an `id` that conforms to the `<BaseParams>` protocol.

Next I created a `DiagramRequest` Class inherited from `BaseRequest` and it has a property whose type is `DiagramParam`, which is class that conforms to the `<BaseParams>` protocol.

I think it is safe for compiling, but Xcode still warns that:
`Property type 'DiagramParams *' is incompatible with type 'id<BaseParams>' inherited from 'BaseRequest'`

I wonder why.

Simplified Demo is here:

BaseRequest.h

```
@interface BaseRequest

@property (nonatomic,retain) id<BaseParams> params;

@end


@protocol BaseParams <NSObject>

- (NSMutableDictionary *)getParamsDict;

@end
```

DiagramRequest.h

```
@interface DiagramRequest : BaseRequest

//warning: Property type 'DiagramParams *' is incompatible with type 'id<BaseParams>' inherited from 'BaseRequest'
@property (nonatomic,retain) DiagramParams *params;

@end


@interface DiagramParams : NSObject <BaseParams>

@property (nonatomic) int id;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *city;

- (NSMutableDictionary *)getParamsDict;

@end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The warning might be removed by placing the `DiagramParams`'s interface definition before `DiagramRequest`'s.

See my answer here.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/14632135/1347502 which removes the warning for a slightly simpler setup.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with a class DTTextRange which is a subclass of UITextRange and all UITextInput methode require UITextRange which is an abstract class.

If I have a property selectedTextRange that specifies DTTextRange as type get the same warning as you that DTTextRange is not compatible with UITextRange.

The only way how I was able to quench the bug was to use the superclass in my property as well.

In short I would love to be able to do the same as you, let us know if you find a way to change a property type.

If not, you have to remove the subclass property and use the id  instead.